# how to represent "cardID" in glass

Tags: google-glass

I'm as Google glass development program,now i have two cards in an activity, And i want to tap  the two cards respond to different events .   I tried to use cardID==card1 or cardID==card2 in keyDown method but failed, because not have the variable cardID ,who can tell me how to represent the variable "cardID".

Comment: Shouldn't you be testing the value of the CardID, not whether is is the same as a different object? That is:  if ( CardID.equalsIgnoreCase("string")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140589/unable-to-get-the-card-index) would help you. In the code i posted just call the getSelectedItemPosition() inside the long press gesture detector.

Comment: thanks ! i used the method mScrollView.getItemAtPosition(position).equals(). And the problem has been solved!